# What does \Sexpr[results=rd]{} exactly mean in Rd?

Tags: r

I have spent a few hours on the R-exts manual and the documentation of
`parse_Rd()` (as well as the PDF document in the references), but I
still have not figured out what `results=rd` means or how to use it. I thought I could
use an R code fragment to create an Rd fragment dynamically. Here is
an example, in which I was expecting the output to be a describe list
`<DL>` in HTML, but it turns out not to be true.

```
des <- "\\describe{\\item{def}{ghi}}"
con <- textConnection(c("\\title{abc}\\name{abc}",
                       "\\details{\\Sexpr[results=rd,stage=build]{des}}"))
z <- parse_Rd(con)
Rd2HTML(z, stages = "build")
close(con)
```

the output under R 2.13.2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html><head><title>R: abc</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="R.css">
</head><body>
<table width="100%" summary="page for abc"><tr><td>abc</td><td
align="right">R Documentation</td></tr></table>
<h2>abc</h2>
<h3>Details</h3>
<p>defghi</p>
</body></html>
```

I was actually building a package with Rd's containing `\Sexpr{}`
instead of really using `Rd2HTML()`; the content was not rendered after
I run R CMD build.

Has anybody ever tried to generate Rd fragments dynamically with `\Sexpr{}`? Thanks!

---

A summary of answers

- A few people have confirmed that this worked under R 2.13.1, but not later versions (2.13.2 or higher)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example works for me with:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.13.1 Patched (2011-07-08 r56332)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=C              LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] tools     stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[8] base
```

I get:

```
> Rd2HTML(z, stages = "build")
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html><head><title>R: abc</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="R.css">
</head><body>

<table width="100%" summary="page for abc"><tr><td>abc</td><td align="right">R Documentation</td></tr></table>

<h2>abc</h2>

<h3>Details</h3>

<p><dl>
<dt>def</dt><dd>ghi</dd></dl>
</p>


</body></html>
```

I think I understand this a bit better now having gone through some of the permutations.

This

```
\name{foo}
\alias{foo}
\title{foo bar}
\description{
blah blah blah
}
\details{
\Sexpr[results=rd, stage=render]{"\\\\describe{\\\\item{def}{ghi}}"}

\Sexpr[results=rd, stage=render]{(des <- "\\\\describe{\\\\item{def}{ghi}}")}

\Sexpr[results=rd, stage=render]{tools:::Rd_expr_PR(1234)}
}
```

works, for example when processed via:

```
R CMD Rd2pdf foo.Rd
```

As I was writing this directly in a file, I had to escape the escaping `\` also, otherwise I was getting errors when processing the Rd file.

I used `stage=render` because during these demonstrations, as I was not building a package (but as I say, your example works for me).

This also works fine when parsed and rendered as HTML:

```
> foo <- parse_Rd("foo.Rd")
> Rd2HTML(foo)
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html><head><title>R: foo bar</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="R.css">
</head><body>

<table width="100%" summary="page for foo"><tr><td>foo</td><td align="right">R Documentation</td></tr></table>

<h2>foo bar</h2>

<h3>Description</h3>

<p>
blah blah blah
</p>


<h3>Details</h3>

<p>

</p>
<p>
<dl>
<dt>def</dt><dd>ghi</dd></dl>

</p>
<p>
<a href="https://bugs.R-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=1234">PR#1234</a>
</p>


</body></html>
```

A slightly longer example, showing several ways in which this can be used, employing three variations on a theme:

1. Produce a character vector by hand]
2. Produce a character vector and arrange for it to be printed `(....)`
3. Produce a character vector in one `\Sexpr` statement, producing no output, but print this vector via a second `\Sexpr` statement.

This is the contents of the file now:

```
\name{foo}
\alias{foo}
\title{foo bar}
\description{
blah blah blah
}
\details{
\Sexpr[results=rd, stage=render]{"\\\\describe{\\\\item{abc}{ghi}}"}

\Sexpr[results=rd, stage=render]{(des <- "\\\\describe{\\\\item{def}{ghi}}")}

\Sexpr[results=hide, stage=render]{des2 <- "\\\\describe{\\\\item{xyz}{ghi}}"}
\Sexpr[results=rd, stage=render]{des2}

\Sexpr[results=rd, stage=render]{tools:::Rd_expr_PR(1234)}
}
```

It renders fine using `R CMD Rd2pdf foo.Rd`.

It appears you need to to extra escape any `\` when writing this in an Rd file, and if you are trying this by producing a single file to be parsed and rendered, you need `stage=render`.